# JBoss(Tomcat)/Apache connection

Tags: jakarta-ee, jboss, web-deployment

I'm running a JBOSS AS 7.1.1 server and a separate apache web server.  I have two EAR deployments on the JBoss server each having an apache virtual host configuration on the web server. One works, the other doesn't.  Both deployments use RESTEasy (although I don't think that's the issue here), and both work with the jboss-server:8080 interface.

The most significant difference to my mind is one uses the 2.4 version of , the other uses the new 3.0 version.

Here are the web-app for the 2.4, working deployment:

```
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee"
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd"
 version="2.4">

  <display-name>Sokoban Mobile WAR</display-name>

  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>javax.ws.rs.core.Application</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

And here is the not working 3.0 deployment:

```
<web-app
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
    version="3.0" >

  <display-name>Voyager Web Application</display-name>

  <listener>
    <listener-class>
      org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.ResteasyBootstrap
    </listener-class>
  </listener>

  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>Resteasy</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>
      org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher
    </servlet-class>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>
    javax.ws.rs.Application
      </param-name>
      <param-value>
    com.nutrastat.voyager.web.VoyagerApplication
      </param-value>
    </init-param>
  </servlet>

  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Resteasy</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

Both deployments have a jboss-web which looks something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<jboss-web>
  <context-root>/dir</context-root>
</jboss-web>
```

`dir` being replaced with the appropriate context as configured in the apache setup.

So what do I need to do to deploy using the 3.0 version of web-app?

Thanks for your help

Comment: Is the problem that this is accessible on `*:8080/2.4/ && *:8080/3.0/` but not on the public instance `*:80/2.4 && *:80/3.0 <--broken`? Or am I misreading your problem?

Comment: Hi Daniel.  I'm afraid you're missing the problem.  2.4 & 3.0 are the versions of the web-app XML files used in the configuration of the two apps.  Both apps work find on the 8080 port of the JBoss server.  But only one (the app using version 2.4 of the configuration XML file) works from the webserver.

Comment: Sorry if my phrasing was off, that's what I was asking. It sounds like you have a configuration problem with Apache/whatever you're using. Usually you have to mount each instance separately. How are you hosting it and what are your config files?

Comment: Hi Daniel, I don't think it is with Apache.  The error reported has a "JBoss Web/7.0.13.Final" footer.  As the same Apache config get the 2.4 version deployment, my question is: Why can't it find it with almost the same config in 3.0?

Comment: What's the error? Those usually have some information as to why things are happening.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution to my problem.  It wasn't a configuration issue, it was an error in the URL.  Finger trouble on my part.

My thanks to Daniel for his help.  He forced me to look very closely at what I was doing, and thereby I found my silly mistake.